# slick insert query with forceInsertQuery

Tags: scala, slick

I need to copy table to another same schema table.
I would like to do something like
`insert into table1 select * from table2`

In slick, it seems possible to insert with queries.
There is a function with signature `.insert(:Query)`

In my table I defined a "id" column with auto-increment option.
However slick automatically omit auto-increment column except using `forceInsert` method.
In this case, column number doesn't match if I print the sql out:

```
val table = TableQuery[Table_X]
println(TableQuery[Table_Y].insertStatementFor( table.take(1000) ))
```

insert statement is lack of an "id" column, but `table.take(1000)` include it.

How can I solve this problem?
I see some functions called `forceInsertQuery` in the source code of slick on github. I am not sure whether this can help me or not